# How to get the IPv6 headers on WIndows using raw-socket?

Tags: windows, ipv6, ethernet, packet-sniffers, raw-sockets

I would like to implement a sniffer for incident response and forensic investigations, to sniff the traffic and identifying malicious packets and C2 (C&C -Command and Control) IP.

In incident response i can't install `npcap`/`winpcap` or other librairies detected by antivirus softwares and i should use the faster way to sniff the local traffic. So i would like to develop a simple CLI sniffer (it must be launched on Windows core servers) in a simple executable file to copy/paste it on the server and launch it with admin privileges.

Context example: a ransomware is running on a server and exfiltrate data, there are some NAT (Network Address Translation) between firewalls and the server (so it's difficult to identifying the the malicious traffic).

I write a POC in python [on my github](https://github.com/mauricelambert/NetworkSniffer).

How i use my raw socket:

```python
from socket import socket, AF_INET6, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_IP, IPPROTO_IPV6, IPV6_PKTINFO, SIO_RCVALL, RCVALL_ON, RCVALL_OFF
sock = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_IP)
sock.bind(("<IPv6 address>", 0))
sock.setsockopt(IPPROTO_IPV6, IPV6_PKTINFO, 0)
sock.ioctl(SIO_RCVALL, RCVALL_ON)
while True:
    data, source_address = sock.recvfrom(65535)
sock.ioctl(SIO_RCVALL, RCVALL_ON)
sock.close()
```

What i get when i sniff a ICMPV6 packet:

```
0000  80 00 68 62 00 01 42 dc 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68  ..hb..B.abcdefgh
0010  69 6a 6b 6c 6d 6e 6f 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 61  ijklmnopqrstuvwa
0020  62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69                          bcdefghi
```

It's just the *data* section without any IPv6 headers so i can't see IPv6 address and protocol type (so i can't parse data).

What i want:

```
0000   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 60 00   ..............`.
0010   00 00 00 28 3a 80 fe 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 12 23   ...(:.*........Z
0020   34 45 56 65 67 78 fe 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   :(B.@.*..P@.....
0030   00 00 00 00 12 23 80 00 68 6a 00 01 42 d4 61 62   .... ...hj..B.ab
0040   63 64 65 66 67 68 69 6a 6b 6c 6d 6e 6f 70 71 72   cdefghijklmnopqr
0050   73 74 75 76 77 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69         stuvwabcdefghi
```

Here i have the Ethernet frame, i would like it but for if you can help me to get only the IPv6 headers, it's okay. If you know how i can get the full ethernet frame, packet and segment it's better for me.

I see IPV6_HDRINCL but it's only to send IPV6 headers not to receive it and i see this [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3542), i don't find what i search.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/tcp-ip-raw-sockets-2 For IPv6 (address family of AF_INET6), an application receives everything after the last IPv6 header in each received datagram regardless of the IPV6_HDRINCL socket option. The application does not receive any IPv6 headers using a raw socket.

Comment: Yes, I see that, so you confirm that there is no way to have IPv6 headers ? Do you know how I can analyze the data received ? Because I don't know which protocol is used, I can't parse TCP, UDP, ICMPv6 or other protocols ? I don't understand why Microsoft makes a raw socket where we can't analyze the data received...

Comment: Why not just use the built-in `netsh trace` functionality to get a packet capture?

Comment: Thank you! It's interesting but it's not really what I'm looking for. I am looking for a modular and customizable solution to be faster on an investigation. But it's better than nothing.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/tcp-ip-raw-sockets-2?redirectedfrom=MSDN#limitations-on-raw-sockets